# JS function is passed a different value depending on whether I'm executing or debugging

Tags: javascript, html, css

PROBLEM: Element with id "containerLnkMenu" does not center correctly in it's parent div when passed into the js function "centerElementYParent" unless I put a break point in the function using google chrome's debugger.
The "getComputedStyle(f, null)" call returns a "0px" for height if executed normally so I end up with a '-57px' for the margin-top.

COMMENT: So I found a few people that had similar problems on the internet, but I couldn't find a way to map their solution to my needs.
Any help on this would be appreciated.
Let me know if you need me to explain anything further.
I would prefer a detailed response or links to further reading, that is related to my issue (so I can learn from this error), but any related/helpful comment is welcome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="btnMenu" class="borderRadius" style="top: 10px; left: 10px;" onClick="btnMenuClicked(this)">
   <div id="bar1" class="bar"></div>
   <div id="bar2" class="bar"></div>
   <div id="bar3" class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu" class="borderRadius" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
   <div id="containerLnkMenu">
    <a id="lnkNews" class="centerTxt lnkMenu" href="">NEWS</a>
    <a id="lnkFiles" class="centerTxt lnkMenu" href="">FILES</a>
    <a id="lnkTree" class="centerTxt lnkMenu" href="">TREE</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script>
  function btnMenuClicked(e) {
   animateBtnMenu(e);
   var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
   var menuStyle = window.getComputedStyle(menu, null);
   if (menuStyle.width == '0px' && menuStyle.height == '0px') {
    openMenu(menu, menuStyle, e);
    centerElementYParent(document.getElementById('containerLnkMenu'), document.getElementById('menu'));
   } else {
    closeMenu(menu, menuStyle, e);
   }
   
  }
  
 </script>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}

a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Class Tools */
.centerTxt { text-align: center; }

.borderRadius { border-radius: 5px; }

.bar {
    height: 5px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    background-color: #2E0A91;
}

.lnkMenu {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFD500;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

/*--- navigation ---*/
#btnMenu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: 0.8s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#btnMenu:hover { background-color: #2E0A91; }

#btnMenu:hover .bar { background-color: #D4B100; }

#bar2 { margin: 5px 0 5px 0; }

.change #bar1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-10px, 4px);
    width: 141%;
}

.change #bar2 { opacity: 0; }

.change #bar3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-10px, -4px);
    width: 141%;
}

#menu {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.8s;
    background-color: #2E0A91;
}
```

```js
//NAME:          centerElementYParent
//DESCRITPTION:  e = element to center, f = parent element
//               Adds margin top to e in order to vertically center element within parent (f)
function centerElementYParent(e, f) {
    var eStyle = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
    var fStyle = window.getComputedStyle(f, null);
    console.log(fStyle.height);
    var eHeight = parseInt(eStyle.height.slice(0, eStyle.height.length - 2));
    var fHeight = parseInt(fStyle.height.slice(0, fStyle.height.length - 2));
    var marginTop = ((fHeight - eHeight)/2) + 'px';
    e.style.marginTop = marginTop;
}

//NAME:         animateBtnMenu
//DESCRIPTION:  Attaches the 'change' class to the btnMenu element.
function animateBtnMenu(e) {
    e.classList.toggle('change');
}

//NAME:         openMenu
//DESCRIPTION:  Applies a width and height to the menu whilst moving the menu button respectivley
function openMenu(e, eStyle, f) {
    e.style.height = '250px';
    e.style.width = '300px';
    var eStyle = window.getComputedStyle(e, null);
    f.style.left = '310px';
    f.style.top = '260px';
}

//NAME:         closeMenu
//DESCRIPTION:  Sets width and height of the menu to 0 and moves the menu button respectivley
function closeMenu(e, eStyle, f) {
    e.style.width = '0px';
    e.style.height = '0px';
    f.style.top = '10px';
    f.style.left = '10px';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because the element you want to center didn't rendered on the right position yet. Try adding setTimeout to call the function.

```
openMenu(menu, menuStyle, e);
setTimeout(function() {
      centerElementYParent(document.getElementById('containerLnkMenu'), document.getElementById('menu'));
}, 800);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that ago as soon as I can.
Could you explain why the element wouldn't have rendered correctly before the function was called?

Comment: @marmitegeek I am just making an assumption there since you used transitions in your css.. Because of the animation effects, it might not be in its full size, right after you called "openMenu" function.

Comment: I agree with that assumption. It makes sense to me. I'll mark this as the answer but I'm thinking I may just hard code the margin for this element. I dunno - I'll mess about with some other things and see what I like best. Thanks for the help.